# push notifications in titanium

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, titanium

I nedd to create push notifications for my app that works on Android and IOS.
I have read the docomention but can't figure out how to puth this to work.

Hase someone an exmaple code that works that can show it to me so I can see how it works?
I have tried this on IOS:

var deviceToken;

```
Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
    success : function(e) {
        deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
        alert("deviceToken = " + deviceToken);
        //subscribeToChannel();
    },
    error : function(e) {
        alert("Error: " + e.message);
    },
    callback : function(e) {
        alert("deviceToken = " + deviceToken);
        //recebePush(e.data);
    }
});
```

But the success, error pr callback functions ar never fired.

In Android I tried this:

```
// Require the module
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
var deviceToken = null;

// Initialize the module
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success: deviceTokenSuccess,
    error: deviceTokenError
});
// Enable push notifications for this device
// Save the device token for subsequent API calls
function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
    deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
}
function deviceTokenError(e) {
    alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
}

// Process incoming push notifications
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
    alert("Notification received: " + evt.payload);
});
```

But it returns always an error saying: "Failed to register for push notifications! INVALID_SENDER.

I have generated an GCM API Key and GCM sender ID for android an created the certificate for IOS but it does no work

Answer (score 0):

You can find complete step by step guides for configuring push notification service [from here](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Configuring_push_services)

And you can get complete guide for get device token and subscribe device for push notification with example [From Here](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications)

Comment: I have Updated my question, if you could take a look

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your GCM API Key / Sender ID and your APNS certificate with the Appcelerator Platform (in the menu under Apps > YOURAPP > Arrow > Push Notifications).

You need to register those credentials with Appcelerator, and you need to enable Appcelerator Platform Services for your app in Appcelerator Studio.  You should see something like this in your tiapp.xml:

```
<property name="acs-authbase-url" type="string">https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-base-url" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com</property>
<property name="acs-push-api-url" type="string">https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-production" type="string">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</property>
<property name="acs-api-key-development" type="string">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</property>
```